# How to finish() the Activity on home button click in android?

Tags: android

I want to finish the Activity on Home Button Click .
I have below code but not get its click event . but still not get clickevent

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
                System.out.println("Home clicked....");
            return true;

            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: apart this u can finish your activity on `onUserLeaveHint()` bez this method called when user press home key button so just override this method and call finish() in this method.

Comment: is "Home clicked...." sentences is print in logcate or not?

Comment: @user1129443 ofcourse not othervise problem was solved :)

Comment: @parag that means you have put code at wrong place so please update your entire file over here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When *Home button* is pressed, **onStop** method is called in your activity. So what you may do is to add `finish();` in **onStop** method to destroy your activity. Eventually **onDestroy** method will be raised to confirm that your activity is finished.

Comment: +1 This may be through. But it will take a little time. As we press Home button then first Activity goes in onPause() then onStop().

Comment: Yes @Waqas absolutely a micromilli time, we not able to noticed but processor do. Anyways good answer.

Comment: @parag remember, Activity can be stop by other factors too. ex. when another activity comes in top of the stack then also your activty gets finished

Answer (score 6):

You can't handle "Home" button.

You could try overriding some of these methods though: [onStop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29), [onUserLeaveHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29)

Are you sure you need to do this though?
If you could save your current state through the onPause/onSaveInstanceState and recover it later the OS should be able to handle the Activity's life cycle and finish it if needed.
Can you tell us what is preventing you from doing it that way? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
              intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              startActivity(intent);  
              moveTaskToBack(false);
                return true;
           }
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to get Home button click event..that not possible to get so finally i have finish activity on onStop().

Answer (score 1):

finish your Activity on `onUserLeaveHint()` bez this method called when user press home key button so just override this method and call finish() in this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the finish() in the onPauseMethod that way once the home button activity is no longer the main active running activity and enters the onPause method it will stop that activity.

Answer (score 0):

Finish the Activity, when home button Clicked.. Its Working Perfect for me..

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        Log.v("hari", "KEYCODE_HOME");
        onUserLeaveHint();

        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public void onUserLeaveHint() { // this only executes when Home is selected.

    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        Log.v("hari", "if condition working");
        finish();
    }

}
```

but sometimes back button not working when use this code...

Answer (score 0):

You can finish the activity when the activity is brought to the foreground from the icon on the home screen/desktop. See here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/D9CyrSzIm5c

Basically, it says to add *android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"* to your activity.

Answer (score -2):

see this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
            finish();
            System.out.println("Home clicked....");
        return true;

        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: You cant catch "Home" button like this. He already told the he not able to catch key.

Comment: Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.